# Setting up data post refresh of partial copy sandbox. How to satisfy master details relationships without manual effors

Tags: data-loader, refresh, partial-sandbox

We have a plan to refresh one of our partial copy sandbox. we would like to set up all data as it is post refresh as there any many UAT data in sandbox. I searched and found Template based refresh but that is not an option as business only want same UAT data to be set up back as it was before refresh.

We have 5 GB of data and only one partial copy of sandbox.

I have left with few options-

1. Take exports of all data ( around 25 objects) which have many master details and lookup relationship. Manually apply VLookup with new ids from sandbox and insert it back.
2. We have Auto Rabit available with us but its also needed source and destination while doing export of data that is also not possible as source will not be there.

Can anyone please help me is there any other way apart from option 1.

Comment: Do you have an option of creating another partial copy sandbox?

Comment: We use own - backup sandbox seeding, its quick and can be fine tuned to which config object data you want.https://www.ownbackup.com/salesforce-sandbox-seeding-solutions

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you rather than manually apply VLookup for loading every object's records which is very tidious, better to create External Id (text) field in those objects. Then populate those values upon running some scripts or load those values using dataloader.

You can also think of updating that External Id field using that record's Salesforce Id. Because this field will be used of maintaining relationship and uploading the data.

Then export those records as csv.

From dataloader upsert option, you can easily map External Id field for insertion into target sandbox.

This is a proven solution I have worked.

Comment: Thanks Santanu but wouldn't i will have to still satisfy other lookup fields. For example is object A has two masterdetails and 3 lookups then how will that populate. Thanks